# Visual Basic CMD/.bat Issue

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd

I'm beyond the point of confused.. I've tried everything. Currently I'm trying to execute the following script;

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Shell("cmd.exe")
    SendKeys.Send("cd desktop")
End Sub
```

Basically as soon as I add the string `"SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")` the reply is a endless spam of CMD boxes.

I want to be able to access a "desktop" then access a .bat file. That way if i send this program to anyone if they put a .bat file on their desktop it'll read back the same as it would on mine. The only issue is no matter what efforts i put in i only receive SPAM. Please help? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will open a Command Window in a specified folder - is that what you need?
`Shell("cmd.exe /k cd \temp", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)`

**EDIT :**
This will run a batch file on the user's desktop (quotes around the path+name in case of spaces in the path)

```
Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("""" & path & "\test.bat""")
```

Comment: basically.. it's a "POWER ON" button.. i have a bot that requires reaching its folder than typing "node run.js" via cmd. i want this so that if i send the file to someone else, and they have the file on their desktop, that it'll work aswell. that shell only works for one specific computer i believe?

Comment: If you want to run a few commands (i.e. a short batch file) when they press a button, it's possible to shell to a cmd window and execute a series of commands in one go, no batch file needed : `Shell("cmd.exe /k cd \temp && some.exe && another.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)`

Comment: the file isn't a .exe though.. its located in a folder and either has to be open with notepad++ and ran>node run.js or through cmd>node run.js

Comment: Without a very clear and detailed step-by-step description of what you need, I'm a bit lost :)   ..... you want to send someone a batch file that they'll put on their desktop, run it when they click a button...?

Comment: Okay, so basically i'm creating a Program with the buttons "POWER ON" and "POWER OFF." When selecting "POWER ON" it will (attempt) to run the 'Bot' i've created. Now, this bot is not an .exe it's in a folder with a "config.json" and "run.js" basically meaning all the file parts are in a folder, an won't run unless together. I've made a batchfile so that way ANY person who downloads this program and has the batchfile in the same spot will command the "POWER ON" to run for them aswell. BUT, my issue is I don't know how to get CMD to run "cd desktop" "start batchfile.bat" at the same time.

Comment: Once you know the folder path, you can run the batch file with : `Shell("cmd.exe /k cd \the_path && batch_file.bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)` – I'd have to research how to get the desktop path, either in VB/C# or in the batch file itself using standard 'environment variables' as listed here http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx